# Как вставить запись в таблицу MySQL с учетом сортировки по алфавиту?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, сортировка, insert

Есть некая картотека людей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть картотеки состоит в том, чтобы хранить такие вот карточки, в каждой из которых записаны по три фамилии изначально. Каждая карточка пронумерована. Фамилии в карточках и картотеке в целом расположены в порядке сортировки по афавиту.

В MySQL таблица хранящая данную картотеку выглядит так:

- id
- card_number (номер карточки)
- position (позиция фамилии в карточке)
- surname (фамилия)

**Задача:** добавить новую фамилию в картотеку с сохранением позиций фамилией, которые там уже есть, но в ближайшую по сортировке карточку.

**К примеру,** нам нужно добавить фамилию "Иващенко"
Фамилия Иващенко по правилам сортировки должна быть после Иванов и перед Илитаев, но так как нам нельзя менять порядок уже существующих в карточке фамилий, то мы должны просто добавить её в конец карточки №1, после фамилии "Илитаев"

В итоге получается мне нужно каким-то образом для заданной фамилии (например для "Иващенко" №1) определить номер карточки в которую я собираюсь добавить эту фамилию.

Comment: Пока что в голову пришла только мысль перевести это дело на сторону PHP, а именно выбрать срез записей (фамилий) по первой букве из добавляемой фамилии, записать его в php-массив, добавить в конец массива новую фамилию, средствами PHP отсортировать массив, найти в нём добавленную фамилию, найти элемент массива который идет до добавленной фамилии, и определить его ID, card_number и position, ну и всё. Костыльно, долго, но должно сработать...

Comment: А `Ирсеньева` куда добавлять в первую или во вторую. И изначально карточки есть на все буквы. Что если у вас изначально не нашлось 3х фамилий на редкую букву вы карточку заведете и придумаете с потолка третью фамилию для нее ?

Comment: Ирсеньева добавлять в карточку №2, после Иулова, потому что трогать уже имеющиеся в карточках фамилии нельзя. Изначально карточек на все фамилии нет. Если к примеру нам нужно добавить фамилию Иващенко, а фамилий начинающихся на И в картотеке нет, то мы пойдем по алфавиту вверх, т.е. к букве А до первой найденной буквы и сработает тот же самый механизм. Карточки новые заводить нельзя.

Comment: А почему не в карточку номер 1 ? по приведенному вами PHP алгоритму вы найдете именно запись из карточки 1, т.к. по сортировке она перед Ирсеньевым

Comment: Почему не в карточку номер 1? Потому что Ирсеньева по алфавитной сортировке должна быть после Исинбаева. По приведенному мною алгоритму как раз таки в php-массиве у меня Ирсеньев будет стоять после Исинбаева, я найду предыдущий элемент - это как раз Исинбаев, определю его номер карты и вставлю в конец Ирсеньева, получив карту №2 с таким составом: Исаев, Исинбаев, Иулова, Ирсеньев

Comment: Почему по алфавиту у вас Ирсеньев после Исанбаева. В известном мне варианте Русского алфавита буква 'Р' идет _перед_ буквой 'С'. Вы знаете какой то другой алфавит ?

Comment: Ой, пардон, я конечно же ошибся. Да, да вы правы!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from card
 where surname=(
         select max(surname) from card where surname<'Иващенко'
       )
```

Даст ту же запись, которую дал бы приведенный вами PHP алгоритм. Если надо определять некие "расстояния" между фамилиями - что бы найти действительно "ближайшую", то вам и на PHP придется попотеть. Но это в принципе то же решаемо.
Например вы можете аналогичным SQL запросом получить запись идущую после вставляемой и уже между ними двумя на php вычислять какая "ближе"

Если приведенный запрос не вернул ни одной записи, значит задали фамилию которая должна быть первой в картотеке. Т.е. такую запись надо точно добавлять в первую карточку картотеки.

Comment: Как вариант еще: SELECT * FROM card WHERE surname < 'Иващенко'
ORDER BY surname DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: В принципе да, думаю одинаково по скорости